# Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer issue (tried everything)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, windows-7

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, which I have installed Sharepoint Foundation 2010, enabled Desktop Experience, and validated I can pull up the Sharepoint site from other machines.

I have tried using Windows 7 and XP, and no matter what I do, I still get this dreaded error. Here are the things that I have tried that have not worked

- Use IE8 or 9 32 bit only
- Ensure WebClient is set to automatic and running (on client and server)
- Changed Registry for Basic Auth and WebDav
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WebClient\Parameters]
- Added sharepoint site to trusted sites in Intranet in IE
- Turned off Protected Mode in IE

I do not know what I am missing, but it should not be this hard. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you running SSL on the server with a self-signed cert?

Comment: @DylanCristy no SSL at all, just http

Comment: Ok, I don't know what the problem is, then, sorry.  I have run into situations where, if the server was running SSL with a self-signed cert, even though you could access and use SharePoint sites in a browser while having a certificate error, you would need to install the certificate on the client machine and get rid of the error before you could use Explorer View.

Comment: rats, i really don't want to have to call for outside help in the form of a contractor to set this up.